# Create virtual microphone and output sound to it

Tags: ubuntu, alsa, ffmpeg

My goal is testing Video Room Application, so I'm going to create multiple virtual machines with virtual webcams and microphones.

Webcam is working fine with `v4l2loopback`, but microphone is not.

I'm trying to use ALSA.

`ffmpeg -re -i cox.mp4 -map 0:0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0 -map 0:1 -f alsa hw:1`

As a result, Firefox sees `Dummy Video device` and can use it. Firefox also sees `Dummy analog stereo` and `Loopback analog stereo`, but there is no sound from these 'microphones'.

Something wrong with ffmpeg command or with ALSA itself or I'm just doing everything wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the hint `-f alsa hw:1`, I managed to get it working by using `-f alsa hw:1,1` instead. First, I had to enable the virtual microphone with `modprobe snd-aloop` (see this related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/43565890/1176454). Here is the full command I used: `ffmpeg -re -i webcam_record.mp4 -f v4l2 /dev/video0 -f alsa hw:1,1`. I then tested to play the fake webcam and microphone stream with VLC but it did not work. When I tried with guvcview it worked.